# Algorithms for data amount conversions

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone give me the algorithms for me please? The only correct item I've got is:

- 1bit = 0.125byte
- algorithm is 1*0.125

Can anyone give algorithms for:

- bits to KB
- bits to MB
- bits to GB
- bits to TB

Comment: see here for the conversion factors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: 1 bit = 0.25 nibble = 0.125 octad = 0.009765625 kibibyte ...need more?

Comment: thnx sir GODBLESS ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with:

- `1 byte = 8bits`

Then we have:

- `1 kilobyte(kB) = 1024 bytes`
- `1 megabyte(MB) = 1024 kilobyte(KB)`
- `1 gigabyte(GB) = 1024 megabyte(MB)`

You can multiply each side of the last equations with `8` to get the same in bits.

Comment: While these are commonly used, it is actually incorrect. See the link I have posted above.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but there are some disputes about what you should use. The key here is "However, in the computer and information technology fields, several other definitions are used that arose for historical reasons of convenience. A common usage has been to designate one megabyte as 1048576bytes(2^20 B)" in the wikipedia article you reference. For future readers, it is worth to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: thnx sir GODBLESS ^_^

Comment: how to make a decision control for combo box any one?